# Analogue of `top -b` for `ps`

Tags: ps

There is a command I use `top -b | grep <searched text>` to monitor some proccesses. Also, I need some analogue of this command for command `ps aux | grep <searched text>`. I mean I would like to see reqularly output of this command. What is the best way to obtain my purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Use the watch command and so:

```
watch "ps aux | grep <searched text>"
```

You can modify the interval with -n